# C++11 regex pattern match

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Given an ECMAScript regex I'm trying to test a string against the specified pattern. For example the string `"+0.1"` should pass the test. However the result of `std::regex_match` is *false*.

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

std::regex format("^[+-]?\d{1,3}\.?\d?$");
std::string str = "+0.1";

bool match = std::regex_match(str, format); // false
```

I have also tested the regex pattern on [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) and it works.

So what do I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backslash in `\.` and `\d` is treated as an escape character of C++ string literals.

Either use raw string literals (`R"***(^[+-]?\d{1,3}\.?\d?$)***"`) or escape the backslashes like this `"^[+-]?\\d{1,3}\\.?\\d?$"`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de25c348573825e7)</kbd>**